# Solving $\log_2(x)+ \log_x(2)+2\cos(y) \le 0$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $x > 1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

If $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x > 1$, how can I solve the following inequality for $x,y$?

$$\log_2(x)+ \log_x(2)+2\cos(y) \leq0$$

I found this in calculus(functions) problems set. I have no idea about advance inequalities so it'll be great if someone can explain using calculus or simple inequalities.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you forget to say that $x > 1$?  $x = 1$ is a problem, and $x \le 0$ is certainly a problem.

Comment: How can x be 1 or x<=0 man , its on a logarithm base. So not in domain.

Comment: that is exactly what I'm saying.  But you said that the domain was $\mathbb{R}$ ("$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$"), so you made an error.  Also, you didn't answer the question: is $0 < x < 1$ allowed?

Comment: @goos It was'nt given in the question.So i thought it may be understood.No only x>1..

Comment: Simar, I have edited to clarify $x > 1$.  When one introduces a function in mathematical writing it's generally expected that the domain be stated, else it is assumed to be all possible $x$.  In this case, we assumed $0 < x < 1$ or $1 < x$ (this is all possible $x$), but now you state $x > 1$.  So unfortunately, by not stating the domain you caused confusion.  Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\ln x=a>0$(assuming $x>1$) Then  $$\frac{a}{\ln 2}+\frac{\ln 2}{a}\ge2\Rightarrow 
2(1+\cos y)\le 0$$ But $$-1\le \cos y\le 1\quad \forall y\in \mathbb{R}$$ hence $$\cos y=-1\Rightarrow y=(2k+1)\pi$$ Then it implies $$\frac{a}{\ln 2}+\frac{\ln 2}{a}\le 2\Rightarrow a=\ln 2\Rightarrow x=2$$

Another case is when $a<0$. Then using similar kind of steps, you'll get $0<x<1$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: how did you get the last step?

Comment: This doesn't hold in the case $0 < x \le 1$ (in this case $\frac{a}{\ln 2} + \frac{\ln 2}{a} \not \ge 2$.

Comment: Combine the last inequality with the first one to get the equation $\displaystyle \frac{a}{\ln 2}+\frac{\ln 2}{a}=2$ , then you'll get it.

Comment: Note that $\left|t+\frac{1}{t}\right|\ge 2$. There are two cases to consider, $t$ positive in which case everything is easy, and $t$ negative in which case everything is easy too, but in a different way.

Comment: Yes, I have added the two cases into my answer.

Comment: But not correctly. If $a$ is negative, every $y$ works.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay $x = \frac12$ is not the only solution in the case $a < 0$.  Any $x$ in this range works.  You accidentally solved $\log_2(x) + \frac{1}{\log_2(x)} + 2 \cos(y) \ge 0$ instead in this case.

Comment: Oh, right! Any $(x,y)$ is solution, right? Presumably I need to go to bed now.